# Bulk check the HTTP headers of a million domains

Tags: php, python, ruby, http, asynchronous

I'm looking to check the HTTP headers of a million+ domains (i.e. look for 200/404/302)

At this point I don't need the body HTML (although I might later) so it would likely be best to use HEAD requests rather than GET. I understand that some servers dont support HEAD and would be willing to sacrifice those as uncheckable for the sake of keeping things simple.

I've tried a number of solutions written in PHP (curl, multi curl, a couple of DIY curl parallel options) but none of them are fast enough.

I'm happy to use any language, the ideal outcome would be to find a C app that is already compiled and simply takes a list of urls and spits out the headers. For example I use an pre-rolled DNS application for checking the DNS settings of all those domains and all I have to do is open a pipe to it and feed it domains and it spits the answers back as they come in (not necessarily in the same order).

It would need to be asynchronous or threaded to be quick enough.

I explored some python options (like Twisted framework and liburl2) but couldn't get anything reliable up and running.

Hoping someone can help point me to a ready made solutioN!

Comment: Well this doesn't look suspicious at all....

Comment: @RogueCoder of course not. I'm sure there's a perfectly legitimate use for it.

Comment: This is trivial with cURL in many languages.  What problem are you running into?

Comment: @David While that's true, and even if the OP is intending to use this for legitimate purposes, if done improperly or too frequently it could cause issues with the domains he is polling.

Comment: @RogueCoder, That's doubtful.

Comment: @RogueCoder Sorry, my sarcasm didn't translate over the internet well. Anyway, this should be trivial with parallel cURL instances which is probably the best way to go about it.

Comment: @RogueCoder Can you explain what you suspect the OP is trying to do?

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/intro.html#example), especially at libraries based on it. For example: https://github.com/gwik/geventhttpclient

Answer (score 0):

First, for those who downvoted the question due to fishyness: This is what Google does. I am quite thankful that they do. For all we know, this gentleman or lady is building the better search engine we'll all be using 8 years from now.

But As Rogue Coder says: we shouldn't all be doing this carelessly.

About the question: you cannot get headers of a domain. You get headers from completing an HTTP request to a URL.

As for a solution: you could use python with one of the many http libraries available, like the built in httplib. Because of the volume of the requests, you will want to use threading to make a number of requests in parallel. Below example is way too simple. In real life you would use a threadpool. Also, having many simultaneous connections brings its own problems. So: how fast do you want it to be?

```
import httplib
from threading import Thread
import time

hosts = [ 'www.google.com', 'www.yahoo.com', 'nos.nl' ]
responses = {}

class StatusChecker(Thread):

    def __init__(self, hostname):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.hostname = hostname

    def run(self):
        conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(self.hostname)
        conn.request("HEAD", "/index.html")
        res = conn.getresponse()
        responses[self.hostname] = res.status



if __name__ == "__main__":
    for h in hosts:
        StatusChecker(h).start()

    time.sleep(10)
    print responses
```

This would give something like:

```
$ python test.py
{'nos.nl': 200, 'www.yahoo.com': 301, 'www.google.com': 200}
```